# Generate Random number in a range with no repeatation

Tags: java, android, random

I am trying to **randomize** quiz questions from firebase. I am trying to generate random numbers from 0-50 add them in a array and once the number is used I want that number to be removed. But it goes forever with repeatation, here is piece of code that I use to generate random

I am calling updatequestion() on oncreate and 4 choice butons of the quiz.

```
public void updateQuestion (){

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        questionNos.add(i);
    }
    Random r = new Random();
    index = r.nextInt(questionNos.size()-1);
    mQuestionNo = questionNos.remove(index);

    mQuestionRef = new Firebase("https://class9notes-2808b.firebaseio.com/"+mQuestionNo+"/question");
    mQuestionRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String question = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            questiontextview.setText(question);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
    mChoice1Ref = new Firebase("https://class9notes-2808b.firebaseio.com/"+mQuestionNo+"/choice1");
    mChoice1Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String choice1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            bchoice1.setText(choice1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
    mChoice2Ref = new Firebase("https://class9notes-2808b.firebaseio.com/"+mQuestionNo+"/choice2");
    mChoice2Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String choice2 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            bchoice2.setText(choice2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
    mChoice3Ref = new Firebase("https://class9notes-2808b.firebaseio.com/"+mQuestionNo+"/choice3");
    mChoice3Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String choice3 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            bchoice3.setText(choice3);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
    mChoice4Ref = new Firebase("https://class9notes-2808b.firebaseio.com/"+mQuestionNo+"/choice4");
    mChoice4Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String choice4 = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            bchoice4.setText(choice4);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
    mAnswerRef  = new Firebase("https://class9notes-2808b.firebaseio.com/"+mQuestionNo+"/answer");
    mAnswerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String answer = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mAnswer = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    if (questionNos == null ){
        Intent i = new Intent(qiozphy.this,Score.class);
        i.putExtra("Score",mScore);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'goes forever with repetition'? You are just removing one question in your updateQuestion() method. If you call it again, you are again putting 50 more numbers.

Comment: So I have to call it once ? but where?

Comment: Why not put 1-50 in an array and shuffle it.

Comment: @ViralVideos I have no idea what you mean by your question. There is nothing that goes on forever in the code you pasted.

Comment: let me show ful

Comment: check now  full code

Comment: Still no idea what is going on forever.

Comment: these random numbers are generated more than 50 times

Comment: So not forever, you get duplicates.

Comment: can you spot the issue where it is repeating?

Answer (score 2):

By shuffling the list you have all numbers from 0 to 49 randomly positioned in the list:

```
questionNos.clear();  // if not empty 
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    questionNos.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(questionNos);
```

Comment: it will repeat the numbers?

Comment: No, all numbers from 0-49, shuffled in the list

Answer (score 1):

You have this code in your `updateQuestion()`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        questionNos.add(i);
 }
```

So if `questionNos` already has 49 questions from a previous call to `updateQuestion()` you will get 99 questions, with 98 of them duplicate, etc.

Move this to somewhere where it is called only once, like the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Use this piece of Code

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
while (numbers.size() < 50) {

    int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(50); // will generate a random number from 0 to 50
    if (!numbers.contains(random)) {  //will check whether the number is repeated or not
        numbers.add(random); //if number is not repeated then it will add it in array
    }
}
```

Comment: where to put this bro?

Comment: where you want to generate a random number

Comment: I want to generate random number inside updateQuestion() but it creates duplicates means more than 50

Comment: edit your question with your updateQuestion() Function

Comment: so now I can put this piece of code inside updateQuestion()?

Comment: @JawadMalik try not to be condescending.

Comment: how do you think that i am condescending?